# How to Implement FaceBook "Like-IT" Button in Iphone/Ipad?

Tags: facebook, ipad, facebook-fql, facebook-like

I want to interigrate i like it button in my Iphone/ Ipad application please help me out?? with some steps and all the required things ????

Thanks a lot in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you speaking of the "Like" button or the "i like it" stream post?

For the "Like" button, you need to create a UIWebView and then:

- have a page hosted somewhere with your xfbml or iframe like button
- or use NSBundle to inject HTML and javascript and then read it from a string

Either way - you will get a like button working.

For the stream publish, you need to use the iOS SDK to make a graph call to '/me/feed', 'post' etc... with your appropriate params and message.